# $101$-th power of three-digit integer $n$ ends with the same three digits of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-theorem

Prove that if a three-digit integer $n$ is relatively prime to $10$ then the $101$-th power of $n$ ends with the same three digits of $n$.

I tried using modular arithmetic but could only get

$$n^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: This is a matter of confirming that $\lambda(1000)=100$ where $\lambda(n)$ denotes the [Carmichael Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fermat's Little Theorem, if $n$ is relatively prime to $10$, then it is relatively prime to $125$, and
\begin{equation}
n^{\phi(125)} \equiv 1 \,(mod \, 125) \,.
\end{equation}
$\phi(125) = 100$, so we have $n^{101} \equiv n \,(mod \,125)$.
Likewise, we can look at $n^{\phi(8)} \equiv 1 \,(mod \,8)$ to get that $n^4 \equiv n^{100} \equiv 1 \,(mod \,8)$ and $n^{101} \equiv n \,(mod \, 8)$.

Together, they imply $n^{101} \equiv n \,(mod \,1000)$, which is what you want.

Comment: formatting note:  `$\pmod{1000}$` produces $\pmod{1000}$